# How to open njsproj project in Visual studio 2012

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I open njsproj project in Visual studio 2012 it gives an error incompatible project

Answer (score 13):

You need the [Node.JS Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/node-js/).

Answer (score 12):

In Visual Studio, go to **Tools** -> Get tools and Features -> Workloads -> select **NodeJs Development**

Links in older answers are outdated.

Comment: I have Node.js development checked and the njsproj still shows up as incompatible and does not load. Using VS 2017 15.9.7

Comment: I found that after checking the `Node.js` workload, it was still showing as incompatible.  But when I right-clicked the project and reloaded, it opened correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Info for VS 2015:

They moved from CodePlex to GitHub.
New link is https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools#readme
The current version is here http://aka.ms/ntvslateststable.
Today it´s V1.2.